# Subatomic natural units

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, si-units, metrology, absolute-units

In High Energy Physics it seems to be common use to measure everything in terms of eV powers, by assuming $\hbar = c = 1$ (dimensionless). Often times this system of units is referred as Planck units, but from what I've understood Planck units also use $G=k_B = 1$ (dimensionless), thus, for instance, mass is also dimensionless, while in HEP we measure masses in eV.

So what is the actual system used in this case?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Natural_units_(particle_and_atomic_physics)).

Answer (score 1):

**Planck units** is the unit system in which $\hbar=c=G=k_B=1$.

In high-energy physics, temperature is often left out, and we don't care about gravity, so we work by setting only $\hbar=c=1$. This system is typically referred to as **natural units**. Here, since we've only set two constants to unity, we retain one scale, which is why we can measure masses in eV (and everything else in powers of eV).

If you find a resource that refers to the system with $\hbar=c=1$ (but not $G=1$) as "Planck units", then that resource is wrong and doesn't know what it's talking about. That's a serious red flag and an indication that you should drop it and find a better resource (or, at least, to take every technical statement there with a massive grain of salt).